# How can I execute an instance query in graphql-fhir?

Tags: hl7-fhir

This issue is migrated from a question on our [Github account](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/) because we want the answer to be available to others. Here is the original question:

Hello,

Following is the InstanceQuery I tried

`http://localhost:3000/3_0_1/Questionnaire/jamana/$graphql?query={id}`

I am receiving back response as `Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"Questionnaire_Query\"`

So what is the right format I should try ?

https://build.fhir.org/graphql.html has a sample as `http://test.fhir.org/r3/Patient/example/$graphql?query={name{text,given,family}}`.Its working in their server. I cannot get the response When I try similarly in our graphql-fhir.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer from Github:

We are using named queries since we are using `express-graphql`. I do not believe that is valid syntax. Also, the url provided does not seem to work, I just get an OperationOutcome saying the patient does not exist, which is not a valid GraphQL response.

Can you try changing your query from:

`http://localhost:3000/3_0_1/Questionnaire/jamana/$graphql?query={id}`

to this:

`http://localhost:3000/3_0_1/Questionnaire/jamana/$graphql?query={Questionnaire{id}}`

When writing the query, you need to provide the return type as part of the instance query. You should get a response that looks like similar to this(if you have implemented your resolver you will have data and not null):

```
{
  "data": {
    "Questionnaire": {
      "id": null
    }
  }
}
```

and from a later comment:

If you are getting null then you are doing it correctly, but you haven't wrote a query or connected it to a data source. You still need to return the questionnaire in the resolver.

Where you are seeing this:

```
instance: {
    name: 'Questionnaire',
    path: '/3_0_1/Questionnaire/:id',
    query: QuestionnaireInstanceQuery,
},
```

You are seeing the endpoint being registered with an id parameter, which is different from a GraphQL argument. This is just an express argument. If you navigate to the [questionnaire/query.js](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/blob/master/src/resources/3_0_1/profiles/questionnaire/query.js) file, you can see that the QuestionnaireInstanceQuery query has a different resolver than the standard QuestionnaireQuery. So in your [questionnaire/resolver.js](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/graphql-fhir/blob/master/src/resources/3_0_1/profiles/questionnaire/resolver.js) file, if you want both query and instance query to work, you need to implement both resolvers.

e.g.

```
// This is for the standard query
module.exports.getQuestionnaire = function getQuestionnaire(
    root,
    args,
    context = {},
    info,
) {
    let { server, version, req, res } = context;
    // Do query and return questionnaire 
    return {};
};

// This one is for a questionnaire instance
module.exports.getQuestionnaireInstance = function getQuestionnaireInstance(
    root,
    args,
    context = {},
    info,
) {
    let { server, version, req, res } = context;
    // req.params.id is your questionnaire id, use that for your query here
    // queryQuestionnaireById does not exist, it is pseudo code
    // you need to query your database here with the id
    let questionnaire = queryQuestionnaireById(req.params.id);
    // return the correct questionnaire here, default returns {}, 
    // which is why you see null, because no data is returned
    return questionnaire;
};
```